# Pytorch-1.2.0 Error on CrossEntropyLoss: only batches of spatial targets supported (3D tensors) but got targets of dimension

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, mnist

Just resurfaced an old template of mine for basic MLP's and I am a bit rusted. I use CELoss on MNIST (transformed images in tensors).

I tried to unsqueeze to factor in batch size, but it really insists on dim=3 for target tensor.
If anyone could also explain why it now requires this it'd be appreciated.

PS. Seems related to post below, which was not answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58325886/how-to-solve-dimension-mismatch-error-for-cnn-on-images-in-pytorch)

My code

```
train_dataset = datasets.MNIST('../', download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())
test_dataset = datasets.MNIST('../', train=False, download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())

indices = list(range(len(train_dataset.data)))
indices = list(range(len(test_dataset.data)))

random.shuffle(indices)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset,
                                          batch_size=batchSize,
                                          num_workers=1)

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset,
                                          batch_size=batchSize,
                                          num_workers=1)


# Surrogate loss used for training
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
test_loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='sum')


optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
#optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=lr ,weight_decay=weight_decay)


print('Training beginning...')
start_time = time.time()

for epoch in range(1, nbr_epochs+1):
    print('Epoch ', epoch, ':')
    train(model, train_loader, optimizer, epoch,loss_fn)
    loss, acc = test(model, test_loader)

    test_accuracy.append(acc)
    train_loss.append(loss)

def train(model,train_loader, optimizer, epoch, loss_fn):
    model.train()

    for batch_idx, (inputs, target) in enumerate(train_loader):

        #inputs = inputs.view(batchSize, 1,100,100)
        inputs, target = inputs.to(device), target.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(inputs)
        loss = loss_fn(output, target.unsqueeze(1))

        # Backprop
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

And the Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-c6a8cb2b8f18> in <module>
     22 for epoch in range(1, nbr_epochs+1):
     23     print('Epoch ', epoch, ':')
---> 24     train(model, train_loader, optimizer, epoch,loss_fn)
     25     loss, acc = test(model, test_loader)
     26 

<ipython-input-29-d78d7fdaeb4d> in train(model, train_loader, optimizer, epoch, loss_fn)
     10         optimizer.zero_grad()
     11         output = model(inputs)
---> 12         loss = loss_fn(output, target.unsqueeze(1))
     13 
     14         # Backprop

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    545             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    546         else:
--> 547             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    548         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    549             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py in forward(self, input, target)
    914     def forward(self, input, target):
    915         return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
--> 916                                ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction)
    917 
    918 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   1993     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   1994         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 1995     return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)
   1996 
   1997 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in nll_loss(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   1824         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
   1825     elif dim == 4:
-> 1826         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss2d(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
   1827     else:
   1828         # dim == 3 or dim > 4

RuntimeError: invalid argument 3: only batches of spatial targets supported (3D tensors) but got targets of dimension: 2 at /pytorch/aten/src/THNN/generic/SpatialClassNLLCriterion.c:61
```

Where inputs in `train()` for loop is shape (32,1,28,28) and problematic target is (32,1)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including (at the very least) your specifc data loading definitions, to see what shapes your tensors are at runtime.

Comment: Updated the snippet ^^. I used datasets.MNISTs and called dataloader directly on them.